# Why are different answers obtained for a regression F-test when using SSE and R2 formulas?

Tags: f-test

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong with an F-test for the regression - I get completely different answers using SSE and R2 formulas. 
Unrestricted model:
[image]

Restricted model:
[image]

1 restriction is imposed, so q=1 in both cases.

Calculation with SSE:
$F=\frac{SSE_r-SSE_u}{SSE_U}*\frac{N-K}1=\frac{2.252-2.142}{2.142}*48=2.465$, same result given by Stata F-test.

Calculation with R2: $F=\frac{Ru^2-Rr^2}{1-Ru^2}*48$=1216.94
What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Is your restricted model nested within your unrestricted model?

Comment: In my model, alpha=lny-lnk and D=lnl-lnk, so these models are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mark999 notes, these two models can't be compared via an F-test because they aren't nested--they are two completely different models, as is clear from the fact that the total sums of squares are wildly different in the two models.

You can only use an F-test to compare two linear models when the models are of the form
$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x2 + \epsilon$$
and
$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \epsilon,$$
i.e., where they have the same response variable and the predictors in the reduced model are a strict subset of the predictors in the full model.

Comment: Hmm, but in my model, alpha=lny-lnk and D=lnl-lnk, so these models are related.

Comment: "related" is not good enough. To use an F-test to compare them, they have to have *exactly the same response* and *nested* sets of predictors.